# Different tkinter version imported by different version of python

Tags: python, tkinter, pip, python-3.7, python-3.8

I have Tkinter `version 8.6` installed on macOS.
When I run `python3.7` (the default python version when I type python), the tkinter version 8.6 is loaded successfully:

```
python3.7
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> print(tk.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel'))
8.6.10
```

while on python3.8 it is not:

```
python3.8
Python 3.8.6 (default, Oct  8 2020, 14:06:32)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> print(tk.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel'))
8.5.9
```

I need the `8.6.10` to be loaded by `python3.8` too

Comment: @Sayse: `tkinter` is a Python built-in module. And the patch level is based on the version of the Tcl/Tk libraries it was linked to when it was built, not the Python module version.

Comment: @ShadowRanger so, there is a way to fix it?

Comment: The fix is basically to make sure you're using a version of Python that was built against the correct version of the Tk headers and libraries. You've said 3.7.4 shipped with the OS, but you haven't said where you got 3.8.6 from. If it was a pre-built binary, you're probably stuck (or you need to look for a better source). If you built it yourself, you need to fix the `./configure` arguments to inform it where to find the correct version of Tk.